# Redirect a URL with RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect a URL like

```
https://www.domain.com/#new
```

to

```
https://www.domain.com/new.html
```

How can I use `.htaccess`?

Comment: What did you try? Did you expect someone does the job without any effort from your part?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Detect and Redirect from URL with Anchor Using mod\_rewrite/htaccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408664/how-to-detect-and-redirect-from-url-with-anchor-using-mod-rewrite-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `hash` part of the URL is not being sent by the browser to the server, so in the server you can't really use this part to do the redirect.

You will have to use `javascript` code for that:

```
hash = window.location.hash
if (hash.length > 0) {
    window.location = '/' + hash.substr(1) + '.html'
}
```